# Why don't I install package "plotGoogleMaps"?

Tags: r

I ditn't install this package. An error has occurred:
install.packages("plotGoogleMaps")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/ADMIN/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘plotGoogleMaps’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Can you help me?

Comment: Mention your R version

Answer (score 0):

try `install.packages("plotGoogleMaps", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`