# Plot coordinates as points on a map

Tags: r, gps, maps, coordinates

I have read similar questions on this site and haven't been able to replicate the code for my particular dataset (i.e. "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65083749/why-dont-i-install-package-plotgooglemaps; [Plot coordinates on map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130604/plot-coordinates-on-map)). I am trying to plot specific locations (GPS coordinates) as points on a global map. This map would preferably be in the form of a satellite image but any form could also work. I do not, however, have an API key.

I am working in R and a subset of my dataframe looks like this:

| Location | Lon | Lat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Zakynthos | 20.75 | 37.85 |
| Zafaraan | 18.73 | 30.39 |
| Fethiye | 29.06 | 36.67 |

Thanks all
SHoekstra

I have checked out similar questions:

[Why don't I install package "plotGoogleMaps"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65083749/why-dont-i-install-package-plotgooglemaps)

[Plot coordinates on map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130604/plot-coordinates-on-map)

I am struggling to get it to work on my data for some reason.

Attempt 1

```
# My data stored in dataframe called "Data"
library("ggmap")
library(maptools)
library(maps)
mapWorld <- borders("world", colour="gray50", fill="white")
mp <- ggplot() + mapWorld

mp + geom_point(data = Data, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude), alpha = 0.5)
```

Attempt 2

```
library("ggmap")
library(maptools)
library(maps)

lon <- c(Data$Longitude)
lat <- c(Data$Latitude)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(lon,lat))

# USING MAPS
map("world", fill=TRUE, col="white", bg="lightblue", ylim=c(-60, 90), mar=c(0,0,0,0))
points(lon,lat, col="red", pch=16)
```

Attempt 3

```
library("ggmap")
library(maptools)
library(maps)

#Using GGPLOT, plot the Base World Map
mp <- NULL
mapWorld <- borders("world", colour="gray50", fill="gray50") # create a layer of borders
mp <- ggplot() +   mapWorld

#Now Layer the cities on top
mp <- mp+ geom_point(aes(x=Data$Longitude, y=Data$Latitude) ,color="blue", size=3) 
mp
```

Attempt 4 - could not install "plotGoogleMaps" package

```
# Create maps 5
#install.packages("plotGoogleMaps", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
#install.packages("plotGoogleMaps")
#library("plotGoogleMaps")


lon <- c(Data$Longitude)
lat <- c(Data$Latitude)

# make your coordinates a data frame 
coords <- as.data.frame(cbind(lon,lat))

# make it a spatial object by defining its coordinates in a reference system
coordinates(coords) <- ~lat+lon 

# you also need a reference system, the following should be a fine default
proj4string(coords) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")

# Note: it is a short for: 
CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
> CRS arguments:
  >  +init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 

# then just plot
a <- plotGoogleMaps(coords)
# here a <- avoids that you get flooded by the html version of what you plot
```

Comment: Could you post an example of the code you wrote?  You say you're struggling to get it to work, but more details would be nice

Comment: There is another approach discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54759432/world-map-plot-with-latitude-and-longitude-points

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen I have tried the following code but still does not generate a plot (I am still new with R so might be a simple mistake):    # create maps 2

# My data stored in dataframe called "Data"
library("ggmap")
library(maptools)
library(maps)
mapWorld <- borders("world", colour="gray50", fill="white")
mp <- ggplot() + mapWorld

mp + geom_point(data = Data, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude), alpha = 0.5)

Comment: @XaC I will edit my question and provide example(s) of the code I wrote :)

Comment: I think you need to change the section `aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude)` to match the column names in your data frame - possibly `Lon` and `Lat` based on the question?

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen I tried but still no plot :( . I just read about the "mapview" package and this might be able to work for my assignment.

Comment: see the answer by @beeflight31 below - please comment there if that approach works for your data, and if it does then tick that as an approved answer.  If not, comment there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here try the folowwing code
https://datavizpyr.com/how-to-make-world-map-with-ggplot2-in-r/

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

world <- map_data("world")

ggplot() +
  geom_map(
    data = world, map = world,
    aes(long, lat, map_id = region),
    color = "black", fill = "lightgray", size = 0.1
  )+
  geom_point(data=data, aes(Lon,Lat), color="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to get this in the form of a satellite image?